# If $Ax=\lambda x$ is $x^T A$ special?

Tags: linear-algebra

The title kind of says it all, but is there any relationship between the transpose of an eigenvector multiplied with its matrix? i.e. if $Ax=\lambda x$ is there any special result of $x^T A$?

Comment: $$
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}=\lambda \mathbf{x}^T
$$Is that special?

Comment: if the matrix $A$ is symetric then the result become $$(Ax)^T=x^TA^T=x^TA=(\lambda x)^T=\lambda x^T$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^TA = (A^Tx)^T$.  So, it is equivalent to ask "if $Ax = \lambda x$, is $A^Tx$ special?"

The answer to that question is in general: no.  There's nothing special we can say unless we know more about $A$.

Clearly, however, if $A$ symmetric, then $A^Tx = Ax$, so $x$ is also an eigenvector of $A$.  More generally, we should consider **normal matrices**, those for which $A^TA = AA^T$.  Notably, $A$ is normal if and only if it satisfies $\|Ax\| = \|A^Tx\|$ for every vector $x$.  With that in mind, we can see that if $A$ is a normal matrix, then $Ax = \lambda x \implies  A^Tx = \lambda x$ (for any real number $\lambda$).  With that in mind (and its generalization to complex numbers), one may derive the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) for normal matrices.

I hope that's helpful.